# D3.js linear scale [0,1] with a specific number of string tick values [A,B,C,...]

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am using D3.js and I would like to display

- a string scale with a specific number of ticks
- while maintaining a linear range underneath it.

e.g.

- string scale [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,X] with 9 components
- while maintaining a linear range between [0,1]

So if the value

- is 1 the point should fall on "X"
- is 0.95 the point should fall between "H" and "X"
- is 11.11 the point should fall on "B"

I'd like something like this, but of course this doesn't work:

```
d3.svg.axis().scale(y).ticks(9).tickValues([A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,X])
```

Or it's possible to rewrite the texts of the ticks manually, but this is unclean.

Comment: It sounds like you want an ordinal scale.

Comment: Can you give an example? Do ordinal scales fulfill the second point when the value is 0.95, or are they used for categories?

Comment: They wouldn't give you in-between values, no. It sounds like none of the scales in D3 support exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you Lars, I think this should be the answer to this question. Or, alternatively to rename that axis per hand.

Comment: Ok, I'll add this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the scales that D3 provides support exactly what you're looking for. You could either do your own scale implementation, or "hack" one of the existing scales. It sounds like a linear scale would be a good place to start. You could then wrap the function to accept characters and replace the labels on the axis for example.

Comment: I will accept the answer but I think we should provide an example of the hack for future users who are looking for this answer.

Comment: Yeah I did this with dates before I found `extent` - worked pretty well.